# Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ not semisimple as a $\mathbb{Z}$ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Just want to ask: Why is $\mathbb{Q}$ not semisimple as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Here is my attempt:
I know that simple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

So if $\mathbb{Q}$ is semisimple, then, $\mathbb{Q}=\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}$.

Is this a contradiction?

Comment: The $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ have torsion. But $\mathbb Q$ on the other hand..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** It is easy to come up with elements $x \in  \bigoplus\mathbb{Z}/p_i\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$x+x+...+x=0$$

Comment: I get it now! Even for infinite direct sum, each element is a finite sum right?

Answer (score 1):

One of the several equivalent conditions a semisimple module has to satisfy is that every submodule has to be a direct summand. I claim that $\mathbb{Q}$ has lots of nontrivial submodules (exercise), but no nontrivial direct summands (exercise).